# Too Few Parameters Expected 1

Tags: ms-access, syntax-error

I am using front end as Business Objects and backend MS Access database.
I have one field with following syntax and when i pull this field in query getting error like "Too Few Parameters Expected 1"

```
Format(Votes.`Vote Received`,"yyyymm")
```

This syntax is parsing but when pulled this object in query giving error. I think it's something related to quotes on field name but this how that field is named. When i am pulling just below field query not giving error.

```
Votes.`Vote Received`
```

Appreciate your inputs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with square brackets instead of backquotes surrounding the field name.

```
Format(Votes.[Vote Received],"yyyymm")
```

If that doesn't resolve the error, check the spelling of all the items in your query's SQL.

I don't understand why `Format()` is still failing for you.  You can use a different method to produce your "yyyymm" format.  Concatenate "0" with the output from `Month()` and take the right-most 2 characters.

```
SELECT
    Year(Votes.[Vote Received]) &
        Right("0" & Month(Votes.[Vote Received]), 2)
        AS year_month
FROM YourTable;
```

Since that second query also failed, try it directly in Access as a new query.  If that attempt fails, at least it will let you know which item the db engine thinks is the missing parameter ... it will display a message box titled "Enter Parameter Value" and below that title you will find the name of the "missing parameter".  And, if it doesn't fail when run directly in Access ... maybe this is a problem with the way Business Objects interacts with the MS Access ODBC driver.

Comment: I am using ODBC connection and tried with square brackets as well but no luck..but above both approaches works without any issue against MS Access db-- anyway to convert month number to two digit (01-12) without using format function..When i have used Year(date)&Month(date), its giving result but like 20111

Comment: i am going mad now..Year(Votes.[Vote Received]) & Right("0" & Month(Votes.[Vote Received]), 2)...is also giving same error not sure why just Year & Month working

Answer (score 1):

In case it works for anyone else. I had the same problem "too few parameters" and it worked if using back quote for field escaping and single quote for defining date format. Dont know why it worked but you can try.

```
Format(tableused.`fieldused`, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711819%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you need to escape with a backquote:

```
Format(Votes.`Vote Received`, "yyyymm");
```

Comment: Sorry but i am already using escape character ..it seems that when i pasted code at first time it's got removed

Comment: Nathaniel Ford, i agree..not sure why Business Objects giving error