# Too Few Parameters Expected 1-MS Access error

Tags: ms-access

I am using front end as Business Objects and backend MS Access database. I have one field with following syntax and when i pull this field in query getting error like "Too Few Parameters Expected 1"

```
Format(Votes.`Vote Received`,"yyyymm")
```

This syntax is parsing but when pulled this object in query giving error. I think it's something related to quotes on field name but this how that field is named. When i am pulling just below field query not giving error.

```
Votes.`Vote Received`
```

Appreciate your inputs..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Too Few Parameters Expected 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733060/too-few-parameters-expected-1)

Comment: yes..i thought it better to publish in MS Access forum..I even tired replacing mm to MM but no luck..any anyone tell me how to get 01 for first month as Month function gives 1..No format function please

Comment: You didn't need to create a new copy of the same question.  You could have just edited the previous question to add the ms-access tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you wish to convert a year and month to two digits each without using format.

"anyway to convert month number to two digit (01-12) without using format function..When i have used Year(date)&Month(date), its giving result but like 20111"

I suggest you try:

```
Right(Year(Votes.`Vote Received`),2) & "-" & Right("00" & Month(Votes.`Vote Received`),2)
```